# C++ Execute .exe with spaces in path

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    system("start C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\Steam.exe\\");
    cout << "Opening...\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When it opens CMD, it says "Cannot find C:\Program'."

Comment: `"start \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\Steam.exe\""`

Comment: Voting to close, however, on account of this being essentially a typographical error; OP did not realize that the spaces would indicate separate arguments to `start`

Comment: Thanks for all your response. But, I ended up doing it like this:

`_spawnl(P_WAIT, "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\Steam.exe","Arg1","Arg2",NULL);`

Answer (score 3):

(Migrating answer from comment)

Place the path into a string internally:

```
system("start \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\Steam.exe\"");
```

Note: use `\"` to create a quotation mark within a string.

Answer (score 2):

Thete's no need to escape with `\`. You could use raw string literals. Like this.

```
system(R"(start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe")");
```

or

```
system(R"(start C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe)");
```